# Кастомная загрузка классов Java

Tags: java

Добрый день!
Реализовал свой собственный загрузчик, переопределив **findClass(..)**. Загрузка происходит  без ошибок.Но если системный загрузчик обнаружит в **classpath** валидный класс, то и загрузит его.Мой кастомный **find()** вызван не будет!
Можно ли это как-то избежать, что бы загружать классы по-своему. даже если они есть в **classpath** ?

Comment: Ого, ну и вопросы у вас. Плагинную систему пишете?

Comment: @VladD можно и так сказать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так работают загрузчики в jvm. Сначала вызывается родительский загрузчик и только если он не найдет класс то дочерний загрузчик будет искать класс сам.

Надо переопределить `loadClass(String, boolean)` и для тех класов, которые должны быть загружены данным загрузчиком самому вызывать findClass, а для остальных использовать существующукю схему.

```
protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
            if (name.startsWith("myspecificclasspackage")) {
                Class c = findLoadedClass(name);
                c = c == null ? findClass(name) : c;
                if (resolve) {
                    resolve(c);
                }
                return c;
            }

            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
       }
    }
```

Comment: кажется непростым самому переопределять loadClass

Comment: @voipp, не очень сложно. Как вариант можно убрать собственные классы из classpath тогда и переопределять loadClass не нужно будет